# How to set limits to specific components of an equation when plotting them?

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot a simple function demonstrating the number of bananas produced over a period of 30 days by two factories which produce 2 and 4 bananas per day respectively.
Represented as an equation:

`y(t)=100+2t+4t`

So my question is, what if I wanted to set it so that the factory making 2 bananas a day stops producing after 10 days? How could I code the program so that the `"2t"` component is removed from the equation once `t=10`?

Alternatively, what if I wanted to represent a new factory which produces 5 bananas a day after`t=15`
How do you add/remove stuff like this?

Here's my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.2)

banana_count = 100+2*t+4*t

plt.plot(t, banana_count, 'k-', linewidth='2')
plt.axis([0, 30, 0, 200])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cannot we use **if** statement? And make a new equation?

Comment: Well I'm wondering what is the most efficient way. How would I incorporate an if statement into the code? Are you saying that you would have two equations and that the if statement will toggle between using either after "t = desired" has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of them as separate components.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
```

You have time and a base array to do operations on:

```
time = numpy.arange(0, 30, 0.2)
blank = numpy.zeros_like(time)
```

Your base bananas (the 100 term) is just a constant array:

```
start_bananas = blank.copy()
start_bananas.fill(100)
```

Then consider the first factory. There are two days to care about: day 0 and day 10.

```
factory_one = blank.copy()
day_0  = numpy.searchsorted(time, 0)
day_10 = numpy.searchsorted(time, 10)
```

From day 0 to day 10 it produces 2 a day:

```
factory_one[day_0:day_10+1] = time[day_0:day_10+1] * 2
```

Then it stays constant:

```
factory_one[day_10+1:] = factory_one[day_10]
```

Consider factory 2:

```
factory_two = blank.copy()
```

From day 15 onwards, it increases by 4 per day:

```
day_15 = numpy.searchsorted(time, 15)
factory_two[day_15:] = time[:-day_15] * 4
```

The total bananas is the sum of these:

```
bananas = start_bananas + factory_one + factory_two
```

Then you can plot them:

```
pyplot.plot(time, bananas, 'k-', linewidth='2')
pyplot.show()
```

---

There are more efficient mathematical ways to do this, but I wanted to get the basic principle across.

Comment: Ahh okay. Just out of curiousity what exactly does "blank.copy()" every time you set it for one of the components of the equation?

Comment: `blank` is just an array of the right size, filled with 0. I copy it so I don't keep changing the same array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `numpy.clip` like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.2)
t2 = t.clip(max=10)

banana_count = 100 + 2*t2 + 4*t

plt.plot(t, banana_count, 'k-', linewidth='2')
plt.axis([0, 30, 0, 200])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a quick and useful solution, although t1 in line 5 should be changed to t.

Comment: @user155876 Yes, it was a typo ;)